# How not to reload webview on screen rotation?

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview which loads content from URL. However, the webview reloads the content on screen rotation, which I would like to avoid.

I have checked similar questions on SO which all recommended either:

1. Putting orientation into `android:configChanges="orientation..."` which is generally discouraged and I don't want to use it
2. Or saving the webview's state with `webView.saveState(outState)`

---

As for the 2nd option, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#saveState(android.os.Bundle)) now states:

> Please note that this method no longer stores the display data for this WebView. The previous behavior could potentially leak files if restoreState(Bundle) was never called.

Which means that it's not the solution either. Is it possible to solve this?

Comment: *In general*, `android:configChanges` should be avoided, because the "cure" (manually manipulating each UI element to ensure that it is correct post-change) is usually worse than the "disease" (using viewmodels and the saved instance state `Bundle`). Occasionally, `android:configChanges` is the better solution, and yours is probably one of them. Just bear in mind that `orientation` is not magic; if you are not including *every* possible value in `android:configChanges`, then you still need viewmodel/saved instance state for those cases you leave out of `android:configChanges`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see, thank you. And what would you suggest if my webview is inside a fragment and I rely on the native "on rotation behavior" on other screens?

Comment: That's one of the reasons I did not post an answer, as I don't have a good solution for that problem. :-(